# Solve $x^TAx=k$ with $k=$cte?

Tags: matrices, quadratics, quadratic-forms, ellipsoids

How can we solve the following equation:
$$
x^TAx=k
$$
if $k$ = a constant and A is a positive-definite and symmetric matrix, $x$ is a vector. I can clearly see that in 3d we have an infinite set of solutions but I cannot formulate it in a mathematical way.
Thanks

Comment: In 2D this is an ellipse, and in 3D an ellipsoid.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *solve following equation*? There is as you say an infinite number of solutions represented by an hypersurface.

Comment: You might find it helpful to use the Cholesky factorization of $A$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I mean finding the equation for $x$ and use the formula to show there is an infinite set of solutions.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I know the eignen decomposition, but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After diagonalization of the matrix (which is a rotation of the basis), the equation becomes

$$\lambda u^2+\mu v^2+\nu w^2=1,$$

which is the equation of an ellipsoid, as $\lambda,\mu,\nu>0$. (If you make $w$ constant, i.e. cut with a plane, you should recognize the equation of an ellipse.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. can you please explain how you achieved the transformation from the equation in the question to the ellipsoid equation? Thanks again

Comment: @lalaland: do you know what diagonalization is ?

Comment: No, but I guess to transform a matrix to a diagonal (vector)

Comment: @lalaland: then read your equation as if the matrix was diagonal.

Comment: So if I understand, if I can decompose $A$ as $QDQ^T$, I can remove the Q since they are eigenvectors of $A$, is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure what happens with the $Q$ and $Q^T$

Comment: @lalaland: you work in the Eigenbasis.